# How to create a reversed SVG Logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm very new to svg and adobe illustrator and I'm struggling with it.
I want to create a svg logo wich is tranparant but the outline is filled.
I want to use it to scale up on scroll

Here is an example what I mean

[image]

Thank you very much for your time and help.

The link to the site is `https://phive.pt/`

Comment: Hi Dario, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. We'd really appreciate an image of your intended effect next to (or instead of) the link to the site, which looks rather spammy. You can [edit] your post to include an image. Thanks! Do have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to understand the Stack Exchange format and what is on and off topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I removed the link and added the screenshot

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the link entirely - because that's the only way we can find out what's going on.  You can disable a link by highlighting it as code, so it doesn't; look so spammy. I've added it back in case someone can tell you how they've implemented it on the site.

Answer (score 3):

The SVG isn't reversed. It's just a regular SVG - a letter-form with a black fill.

You can see the SVG [here (direct link to SVG)](https://phive.pt/public/imgs/id/safari-pinned-tab.svg)

The effect is created by other means - I suspect javascript/css/html5 etc, etc.

And just in case the link dies, here's the code. And a screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="260.000000pt" height="260.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 260.000000 260.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.11, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2013
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,260.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1167 2304 c-1 -1 -114 -5 -252 -8 -137 -4 -279 -9 -315 -12 -104 -8
-153 -12 -186 -13 l-31 -1 0 -199 0 -199 30 -6 c16 -3 40 -6 52 -6 l23 0 -2
-576 -1 -577 -40 -4 c-22 -2 -45 -5 -51 -7 -8 -3 -12 -63 -11 -200 0 -192 0
-196 21 -197 31 -1 788 -1 808 0 14 1 16 22 16 199 1 146 -2 199 -11 200 -7 1
-25 3 -42 5 -16 2 -35 5 -41 5 -8 1 -11 38 -10 112 l1 109 215 5 c118 2 231 7
250 11 213 37 299 66 401 135 118 81 201 217 226 376 10 61 10 275 0 329 -23
124 -72 222 -151 300 -110 109 -252 166 -501 201 -61 8 -392 23 -398 18z m353
-469 c95 -38 129 -101 125 -231 -6 -173 -104 -232 -380 -228 -60 1 -117 3
-126 3 -14 1 -16 27 -16 234 0 127 2 236 5 241 2 5 82 6 176 4 132 -4 181 -9
216 -23z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]